# Unable to add canonical tag in opencart

Tags: php, opencart, canonical-link

For some strange reason I am unable to add the canonical tag to opencart 1.5.2.1 product pages and category pages. I've made changes to both product.php and category.php but it just doesn't show up in View Source. Can anyone let me know if I missed out something?

Files Edited

1) catalog/controller/product/product.php
2) catalog/controller/product/category.php

Code added

```
$this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_id), 'canonical');
```

after

```
$this->document->setKeywords($product_info['meta_keyword']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried that exact same code on a clean 1.5.2.1 install. Works perfectly. You're either

- Using a custom theme that doesn't support links (unlikely but possible)
- Not saved
- Not uploaded
- Not looking at the source code in the right place
- Not edited the correct controller

Comment: Thanks Jay, I've been trying the whole night and I still couldn't get it to work. There are link tags in the rest of the source so I'm pretty sure that is supported. I really have no idea what is going on.

Comment: this is probably due to the custom theme. Tried on my local, it does work on the default theme. Thanks Jay for listing out the possibilities.

Comment: No problem. Generally the quickest thing to do first is to switch to the default theme, see if that works. If it does, you know the custom theme is at fault